# Как сохранить Java 6jn23?

Tags: java

Я хочу скопировать Java 6 от 23, но почему-то копируется 6 от 36.
Как можно мне на компьютере скопировать, чтобы самостоятельно отправить налоговые отчеты через кабинет налогоплательщика? Я один раз отправляла через Java 6 от 23.

Comment: Не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Не понятный вопрос, но все же попытаюсь Вам помочь.

Скорее всего какая-то программа для отправки налоговой отчетности написана на java. Так вот - java6, сборка 23 должна быть полностью совместима со сборкой 36(последней и самой свежей). Так что не мучайтесь, и отправляйте.

Comment: может там какой хак, который работает только в 23... это же госконтора в совке

Comment: маловероятно